# Put bootstrap indicators in grid form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking to take the bootstrap indicators out of their normal spot inside the slider, and put above an across the carousel a la col-xs-12. The following is what I have so far.

https://jsfiddle.net/podbarron/v1tk3Ly7/

I thought about putting the ol in a div, but the ol and div still have the position property.

```
  <ol id="indicatorOl" class="carousel-indicators col-xs-12">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active col-xs-12"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1" class="col-xs-12"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2" class="col-xs-12"></li>
  </ol>
```

I also thought about taking it outside of the div, but then the active class feature doesn't work. I guess i could make my own. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You can position your indicators absolutely relative to your carousel.

```
.carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
}
```

Live example [here](http://codepen.io/marceloa/pen/jWoXxq?editors=1100) and below.

```css
/*For emphasis*/
html {
  background-color:salmon;
}
.carousel {
  margin-top:50px;
  background-color:beige;
}

/*Relevant code*/
.carousel {
  position: relative;
}

#myCarousel .carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="bs-example">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
     <!-- Carousel indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>   
       <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="active item carousel-fade">
                <h2>Slide 1</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="item carousel-fade">
                <h2>Slide 2</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="item carousel-fade">
                <h2>Slide 3</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel nav -->
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```